# What is the use of verbose = integer in R language

Tags: r

I was trying WGCNA referring this [link](http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/Tutorials/FemaleLiver-02-networkConstr-auto.pdf).
when I tried to execute

```
sft = pickSoftThreshold(datExpr, powerVector = powers, verbose = 5)
```

my whole computer system became unresponsive( kind of hanged). Why is this happening? What is the exact use of verbose in here.
I checked several sites where I found verbose=TRUE/FALSE but I was unable to find the meaning of verbose= integer.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/WGCNA/docs/pickSoftThreshold

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Can you suggest me why this command is making my system unresponsive. I know the data I am using is very large but it shouldn't get hanged.

Comment: Please provide additional information about your hanging issue. I suggest you post it as a new question.